# Getting bytes[] from inputstream in android gives null value

Tags: android

Trying to get bytes data from inputstream as shown in the below code. But, the  bytes variable is null. What might be the reason?                             FYI- Image is available in the given uri, as i can see the image in imageView1.  (Testing on Lollipop).

```
final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
var_Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ui_imageView_browse);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(var_Bitmap);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(imageStream);
OutputStream out;
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
File createDir = new File(root+"master"+File.separator);
createDir.mkdir();


File file = new File(root + "master" + File.separator +"master.jpg");
path=root+"master"+File.separator+"master.jpg";
file.createNewFile();
out = new FileOutputStream(file);
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
```

Comment: the input stream has been read to the EOF by `decodeStream` so there is nothing to read, why do you want to make a copy of your image anyway?

Comment: @pskink, thanks, that is the issue.it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pskink suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608258/getting-bytes-from-inputstream-in-android-gives-null-value#comment78175674_45608258), the issue was that the input stream has been read to the EOF by decodeStream, so there is nothing more to read.

To solve the problem, I created a temporary variable for inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Hope it helps.